# Quotient rule for derivatives..am I making this to complicated

Tags: calculus, derivatives

This is a straight forward question..

When I have something like 10/x (i.e basically whenever the numerator is just a number with no variables)  and I need to take the derivative I go through the whole quotient process knowing first off the 10 will disappear, really meaning my numerator will start with - .

I go - 10 * derivative of denominator all divided by denominator  ^2.

Typically I write it out completely and it feels like maybe I'm making it into some thing that could be done a lot shorter.

Is there a short cut people employ with these straight forward derivatives e.g 50/x, 10/2y ..basically whenever the numerator is just a number with no variables

Comment: simplify first, differentiate after.

Answer (score 3):

If you ever see $$f(x)=\frac{10}{x}$$ just write $$f(x)=10 \cdot x^{-1}$$ and differentiate using the power rule.

You would use the quotient rule to differentiate a fraction composed of a numerator with more than 2 terms of the independent variable.

If you did use the quotient rule to differentiate $$f(x)=\frac{10}{x}$$ we would get:

$$f'(x)= \frac {10 \cdot \frac{d(10)}{dx} \cdot x - \frac{d(x)}{dx}\cdot 10}{x^2} \implies \frac{-10}{x^2}$$

Comment: OP asks about $c/f(x)$, using $10/x$ as an example. You might want to expand your answer.

Comment: Thanks, I changed my answer, and @user3754366 , you can replace the 10 with any constant you want. Also, remember that the derivative of any constant is 0.